# Which ingress documentation to follow? and how to apply nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/

or

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/

Can I just use nginx.conf that is already working? A configMap can be created for the nginx.conf. How to apply the configMap to the following ingress?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
      
spec:

  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.mydomin.com"
      secretName:mydomain-ssl

  rules:
    - host: "*.mydomain.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-webapp
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a config map using the `nginx.conf` refer to this official Google [document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/custom-nginx).

After creating a config map you can use `annotation “snippets”` to apply it to the ingress, you can find the sample yaml below and For more information you can follow this NGINX [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: cafe-ingress-with-annotations
 annotations:
   nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "30s"
   nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "20s"
   nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "4m"
   nginx.org/server-snippets: |
     location / {
       return 302 /coffee;
     }      
spec:
```

Comment: By default, snippets is disabled. The nginx controller is installed using yaml. How to enable snippets when installing controller using YAML? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests. thanks.

Comment: The nginx.conf is complete including rules. So the spec can be empty? thanks.

Comment: comand line option: -enable-snippets. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/command-line-arguments#cmdoption-enable-snippets. Do not know how to add the option when applying YAML file.

Comment: You can directly add into [ingress manifest](https://docs.giantswarm.io/advanced/ingress/configuration/#configuration-snippets) by `enable parsing of configuration snippets, you’ll need to set controller.allowSnippetAnnotations: true`.

Or try `kubectl apply -f your\\\_yaml\\\_file.yaml --set-string controller.enable-snippets=true.`

Comment: invalid option --set-string.

Comment: Open the values.yaml file for the controller, find [controller.enableSnippets,](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/#:~:text=controller.enableSnippets) it will be false by default. Change it to true save and deploy the changes to the controller.